# How to have Json data available to a html view and its javascript code using a Spring mvc controller

Tags: json, model-view-controller, spring-mvc

I use a Spring MVC controller method in order to display a html view and **that view requires JSON data that is available in the model** i.e. a collection/array of postcodes.

**I thought of outputting the JSON data inline in the html view** inside `<script` tags but before doing so I would like to know whether there isn't a better practice...

Can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/yourmapping", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces={MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE, MediaType.ALL_VALUE})
public String page(Model m){        
    m.addAttribute("postcodes", new ArrayList<String>());       
    return "your-jsp-name";
}
```

Then in your jsp you can access the collection like `${postcodes}` and loop over it or set its string representation into a hidden `span` for example and then your JavaScript can process the data.

EDIT:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var postcodes = "${postcodes}"; 
</script>
```

Comment: I implemented your solution. I actually wanted to avoid putting hidden html in the DOM but never mind... Thanks.

Comment: Well you don't have to use a `span`, you could also access `${postcodes}` in a `script` block -- see my edit.